# Protractor - How to export describe, it and expect to a document/file

Tags: protractor, export, document

Is there any module that reads through all specs and then extracts describe, it and expects from the specs and save it into a document or file?

This would be helpful when documenting the test case.

Comment: I suggest using a Notepad++ plugin. See some suggestions here: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/combine-or-merge-all-text-files-with-txtcollector/

Comment: Thank you Ernst for the tip. I will check it.